# Ошибка ImproperlyConfigured при первой миграции

Tags: django, pycharm

Ошибка `Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead`

В файле **config/urls.py** ничего не подсвечено:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('parser.urls', namespace='parser')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Ранее не сталкивался вообще с такой проблемой. В `urls.py` прописано все корректно. Даже предположить не могу почему ошибка вылетает - сделал так, как всегда раньше делал.

При этом сначала я неверно указал namespace - вылетела ошибка. Исправил и начала вылетать эта ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ написан в описании исключения. В `parser.urls` задан `app_name`?

Пример

```
app_name = "parser"
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ. Да, задан. Проблема решилась просто и странно - я закрыл и открыл пайчарм и все заработало. Не знаю, что за глюк такой